# react select similar function to getOptionLabel function in 1.3 version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, ecmascript-6, react-select

h guys ,
I am making a react app with react select 1.3 version , I need to add a custom function to drop down which includes 2 keys.
I noticed latest react select has a function for this

> **getOptionLabel**

I want to find something similar to this function for react select version 1.3 .
could anyone able to help me on this ?

this is not supported in react select version 1.3 need a function similar to this

```
   getOptionLabel={(option) => `${option.label}: ${option.rating}`}
```

Comment: This one? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select Why not use a newer version instead? 5.4.0 is the current one.

Comment: @ChrisG the older version is used every where in the app so think will cause big issue if changed. so thinking of a short solution without breaking the app

Comment: sure thanks tried and it breaks as the  plugin already modified

Comment: tried labelKey={`${someid} ${stafName}`} then search field is empty

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/pknj7w2367 this sandbox  has 1.3

Comment: Ah, looks like that version wasn't pushed to npmjs.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-forked-bsfbrz?file=/example.js this is like almost my app is it possible to modify this app if can

Comment: currently when we search name is showing in dropdown now I am trying to show color also in drop down   name: "asdf", color: 'red'

Comment: this same like in this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-forked-bsfbrz?file=/example.js

Comment: now when you type in search its showing the name key , i like to add another key also in search sp when you search some item by name or color  both name and color of the item shown for each item in drop down

Comment: getOptionLabel  

you can search above term in below link 

https://react-select.com/advanced similar to this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247118/discussion-between-famo-and-chrisg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relabel the options by mapping the original options array to a new one, like this:

```
const options = colourOptions.map(({ value, label, color }) => ({
  value,
  label: `${value}: ${label}, ${color}`
}));
```

Since the custom `<select>` is now using new objects, you need to make a change to `handleChange` so the original options are used in the state:

```
handleChange = (alteredOptions) => {
  // map altered options to actual options using the value
  const selectedOptions = alteredOptions.map((so) =>
    colourOptions.find((co) => co.value === so.value)
  );
  this.setState({ selectedOptions });
};
```